# Adobe AIR for iOS - Change name below the icon

Tags: flash, air

I can change the name of the application that displays below the icon on the iOS home screen by changing the "name" attribute, but I would like the actual app name to be longer than what displays under the icon. Is there a way to do this with Adobe AIR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible. iOS displays the name of the app under the icon, nothing else. If you want the name of the app to be more than the max displayable characters (indicated as 12 by Craig), you will have to deal with truncation.

It is worth noting, however, that the name that shows in the iTunes Store is *not* the application name. You set that in iTunes Connect. As far as I am aware, the name of the app only shows up in a handful of places, most of the time under the same truncation rules as under the icon. It'll show in iTunes (not the store, but after it is downloaded), in the "Usages" section of the device, and in the device search. Really, if you want your entire app name to fit under the icon and can get it to fit in 12 characters, you should have no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that iOS will truncate an App name that runs wider than about 12 characters. It does something like this: **"Reall...le"** What will you do with a name longer than the one under the icon?

Comment: Right, I want the display name under the icon to be different so that it doesn't get truncated.

Comment: In original question you seem to say that you want the 'actual app name' to be longer than the displayed name. Now are you saying that you want a LONGER displayed name? If so, not possible -- iOS will truncate the name. If not, what ARE you saying?